# How to correctly delete and update array elements?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to send mass email based on certain condition.

I created a dynamic array that stores all the mail addresses. Idealy, if the `checkInbox = true`,
it will remove the email from the array, so that it wont be send to the user.

Now, It is sending to all the user. I try to debug my checkInbox, but it is returning the correct
sender-email address(which is me) within the condition.

Example output of the array with `A = true`

[image]

I can't seem to find my mistake. Any help is appreciated.

**Thanks to  @YowE3K for providing the MCVE example**

```
Sub test()
    Dim fpemail
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 4
    ReDim fpemail(cnt)

    fpemail(1) = "A"
    fpemail(2) = "B"
    fpemail(3) = "A"
    fpemail(4) = "D"

    For i = 1 To cnt
        If fpemail(i) = "A" Then
            Call DeleteElementAt(i, fpemail)
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print fpemail(1) ' displays "A"
    Debug.Print fpemail(2) ' displays "B"
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteElementAt(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal arr As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = index + 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i - 1) = arr(i)
    Next

    ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You would make this a lot easier to understand if you posted an MCVE that didn't mention the Outlook stuff - that is completely unrelated to what I assume is your issue ... that the array after running `DeleteElementAt` is the same as it was before you ran it.

Comment: Yes, I tried debug out the array and you're right but didn't I used it in the IF statement? Shouldn't it remove the `CheckInbox = True` Email?

Comment: Have a look at my answer and see if the MCVE I used is correctly illustrating your issue.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks, after the update it is. Do I need to edit my question to your example?

Comment: Feel free to copy the first code block from my answer into your question if you like, but it's probably not 100% necessary so don't bother if you don't want to.

Comment: I edited your question too since you are now asking deleting and updating array elements. :)

Comment: @L42, thanks, I forget about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An MCVE of your problem would look like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim fpemail
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 4
    ReDim fpemail(cnt)

    fpemail(1) = "A"
    fpemail(2) = "B"
    fpemail(3) = "A"
    fpemail(4) = "D"

    For i = 1 To cnt
        If fpemail(i) = "A" Then
            Call DeleteElementAt(i, fpemail)
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print fpemail(1) ' displays "A"
    Debug.Print fpemail(2) ' displays "B"
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteElementAt(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal arr As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = index + 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i - 1) = arr(i)
    Next

    ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
End Sub
```

There are several issues with that code:

1. The procedure declaration for `DeleteElementAt` says that `arr` is passed `ByVal`.  Therefore only a **copy** of the array is passed to the function, avoiding any possibility of changes affecting the calling routine.  You need to pass it `ByRef`.
2. Once you delete an element from the array (e.g. the first element) what used to be the second element has become the new first element, and what used to be the third element is the new second element, etc.  Thus your `For i = 1 to cnt` loop would be skipping over positions that had been moved to earlier positions.  (Of course, this wouldn't be an issue until **after** the first problem was resolved.)

---

A refactored version of the code might look like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim fpemail
    Dim cnt As Long
    Dim i As Long
    cnt = 4
    ReDim fpemail(cnt)

    fpemail(1) = "A"
    fpemail(2) = "B"
    fpemail(3) = "A"
    fpemail(4) = "D"

    i = 1
    Do While i <= cnt
        If fpemail(i) = "A" Then
            Call DeleteElementAt(i, fpemail)
            cnt = cnt - 1 ' Reflects the fact that we now have one less position
                          ' Don't change i, because we still need to process
                          '     what has now been moved into that position of
                          '     the array
        Else
            i = i + 1     ' Increment i so that we look at the next position
                          '     of the array
        End If
    Loop

    Debug.Print fpemail(1) ' displays "B"
    Debug.Print fpemail(2) ' displays "D"
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteElementAt(ByVal index As Integer, ByRef arr As Variant)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = index + 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i - 1) = arr(i)
    Next

    ' Shrink the array by one, removing the last one
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi your example works great on static array, how can I modify to suit for dynamic array?

Comment: What do you mean a static array?  I used a dynamic array for `fpemail`.  (The bit I had at the top of the MCVE was just setting `fpemail` to be a dynamically created array with four elements to match your example.)  You didn't show where/how you were creating your `fpemail` and `cnt` variables, but I suggest that you don't need to change those bits of your code in any way - just change the loop part of your code to use the `Do While i <= cnt` methodology, and change the procedure declaration of `DeleteElementAt`.)

Comment: My bad, did not check properly with my example. I'm Keep receiving `Script out of range Run-Time error '9'` after `DeleteElementAt` when tried to send email, but I think would be another question.

Comment: If you have the `Debug.Print "Email is being send to TRUE: "; fpemail(i)` still in your code, you should move that to before your `Call DeleteElementAt(i, fpemail)`.  If you try to do it afterwards, and you have just deleted the last element of the array, you will get a subscript out of range error.  And if it wasn't the last element, you would still be displaying the wrong name (because you just deleted the one you were wanting to delete).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a `Collection` in place of your array.
As easy to populate and as easy to read and update.

```
Dim fpemail As Collection, i As Long
Set fpemail = New Collection

With fpemail

    .Add "A"
    .Add "B"
    .Add "A"
    .Add "D"

    For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Item(i) = "A" Then
            .Remove (i)
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print fpemail(1)
    Debug.Print fpemail(2)
End With
```

Comment: I thought of using a `For` loop with a `Step -1` in my code too, but I wasn't sure whether the OP needed to process in a certain order or not.  (I suspect that it **isn't** required, so I'm glad you posted the simpler reverse loop.)

Comment: @YowE3K Yeah, I just thought of presenting an alternative. Arrays are handy but can be confusing sometimes specially for beginners. But couldn't have thought of this if not for your *question deciphering skills*. Lol ;)

Comment: LOL - It did take a while before I realised that all the bits about email addresses and sending emails was really just a smokescreen for the actual problem.  (I was originally thinking I had no hope of working out what was going on.)